# reserve vector memory for cv::Mat of unknown size

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, vector

I want to init a std::vector with a given amount of memory, therefor I have to use `std::vector::reserve`.
I totally understand that it works for datatypes like int float etc.

But how is it supposed to work for a `cv::Mat` wich is basically variable in how much memory it needs depending on the dimensions.

I wonder if there is a way to init the vector with the size of the matrices which are passed into it. Otherwise I guess it wouldn't make any sense to use `reserve()` with datatypes like matrices.

Comment: you want to preallocate the matrix data too?  hard, but you could create either submatrices of bigger matrices, or create matrices pointing to preallocated data.

Comment: No not really, I just thought about how the vector can reserve memory for matrices which size is not defined at this specific point. But as cv matrices just contain pointers to the data it is not really possible for my task.

Answer (score 1):

`cv::mat` Matrices **allocate** the data in the constructor. As you can see [below](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) the data is just a pointer to some data:

```
class CV_EXPORTS Mat
{
public:
    // ... a lot of methods ...
    ...

    /*! includes several bit-fields:
         - the magic signature
         - continuity flag
         - depth
         - number of channels
     */
    int flags;
    //! the array dimensionality, >= 2
    int dims;
    //! the number of rows and columns or (-1, -1) when the array has more than 2 dimensions
    int rows, cols;
    //! pointer to the data
    uchar* data;

    //! pointer to the reference counter;
    // when array points to user-allocated data, the pointer is NULL
    int* refcount;

    // other members
    ...
};
```

The data is not statically stored in the matrice. So each Mat should be the same size.
In your use case using vector doesn't even make sense as you don't seem to need to store objects with different sizes (unless you also plan to add objects derived from cv::Mat)

Comment: Well I've got 81 `cv::Mat` with the same dimensions but different data. That was why Im wondering. For example if I init `vector<int> v1(10)` I assumed that `reserve` would reserve 10 times 4 bytes of integer. So the memory the vector needs would be reserved. Now I understand that `cv::Mat` is basically pointing to the data, not holding it.

Answer (score 0):

Stack size of `cv::mat` is constant at compile time like all other objects. You can learn it by using `sizeof(cv::mat)`. So you can safely use `std::vector::reserve` for any object.